# Android PDF document drawable low quality

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-vectordrawable

I draw vector drawable on canvas and use PDFdocument to save into a PDF file.
My problem is sometimes the quality of the icon is good but sometime is very bad.
I draw on Canvas using this code:

```
iconActivity.setBounds(leftMargin,iconActivityTopMargin,iconActivityRightBound,iconActivityBottomtBound);
iconActivity.draw(canvas);
```

You can see the picture below. They have the same XML properties.
I have searched for some days but I cannot find anything that can help.

```
 android:width="26dp"
 android:height="26dp"
 android:viewportWidth="26"
 android:viewportHeight="26">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it myself. Instead of using vector drawable, I use PNG image and the result is fine. Hope this can help the others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).